# Regex To allow Only number comma separated

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I want to add JavaScript validation to my input.

The Form is generated dynamically as per the information from database.
I have field called regex where i store the expression to be applied to that field So I fetch the regex but how to apply it to the form ?
I want to allow only comma separated numbers how to do this:

This is my generated HTML

```
<tr>
    <td>Codec</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Codec" value="8"/></td>
</tr>
```

This is the regex i want to apply to my input : **^[0-9 _ ,]*$**

What should be my java-script to check the input?

Comment: It depends on what kind of validation you mean. For an on-submit validation, you can use `<input type="text" name="Codec" pattern="[0-9 _,]*" value="8"/>`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So Easy ? Just need to add pattern and then the regex i want to apply ?

Comment: Try and see if it works the way you expect.

Comment: it did not work @WiktorStribiżew my html code is  <input type="text" name="Codec" value="8" pattern ="/^[0-9 _ ,]*$/" />    </td>

Comment: Why do you add `/`s? `pattern` attribute only accepts a string, not a RegExp object.

Comment: Should i keep ^ and $ at the end?

Comment: No, `^` and `$` are added by default. The final regex that will be applied is `^(?:[0-9 _,]*)$`.

Comment: Thanks man this works @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: try pattern method of html input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can validate the input on the html input tag.
Just use pattern="[0-9 _,]*"